# Using filename generation modifier on nonexistent filepath

Tags: zsh, filepath, glob

I want to get the directory part of a path to a nonexistent file. Using the `dirname` command is not a solution as I want to stick with Zsh tools when available.

The goal is to create the directories which will contain the new file using the `mkdir` command.

The point is that using the filename generation modifier `:h` seems to not work on path to nonexistent files:

```sh
$ echo ./.foo/bar/baz(:h)
zsh: not matches found: ./.foo/bar/baz(:h)

$ mkdir --parents ./.foo/bar

$ touch ./.foo/bar/baz

$ echo ./.foo/bar/baz(:)
./.foo/bar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modifier is applied on filename generation, but it can also be applied on parameter expansion.

```
$ foo=./.foo/bar/baz

$ echo $foo
./.foo/bar/baz

$ echo $foo(:h)
zsh: not matches found: ./.foo/bar/baz(:h)
```

Here, the parameter *foo* is first expanded, then the modifier trigger filename generation.

To prevent this, use the syntax shown below:

```
$ echo ${foo:h}
./.foo/bar
```